# Is it possible to host multiple OpenDS instances on one Machine?

Tags: ldap, opends

I am setting up a dev environment for a project where the user requires multiple OpenDS stores hosting separate information in each.

I have tried installing two OpenDS servers, bound to different ports and admin ports, and it installs fine. When I try to start the second OpenDS instance using the startup.bat batch I get a port already bound error on port 5444 (the OpenDS 2 admin port). Trying to connect with the admin console it states that the server isn't running, yet the startup.bat fails.

Is this a problem with OpenDS or the port I am binding to? I am not very familiar with which ports are free and OpenDS during the install procedure suggested 5444 so I assumed it would be free.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to host multiple OpenDS servers on one machine?

Comment: If your intent is to store different information (with a different prefix or namingContext), it might be simpler to create separate backends to host the different prefixes.

Comment: Yep, thats a better solution. Thanks

Comment: BTW Solution is to use a different port, OpenDS assumed 5444 is open but it is instead bound.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, unless you have a requirement to use separate ports, or have some other reason to use different instances, a different naming context might still be best. If there is a requirement for different ports, this can still be accomplished by configuring additional LDAP Connection handlers for LDAP and TLS, and/or LDAPS connection handlers if there is a requirement for SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael,

It's possible to install multiple instances of OpenDS on the same machine as long as each instance uses its own ports. The default ports are 1389, 1636 and 4444 (Unless you're Administrator and have no other directory service running, in which case port 389 and 636 will be proposed).
setup.bat tries to detect if ports are already used, but may fail to do so. You can choose whatever port above 1024.

As Terry mentioned, it might be easier to configure a single instance with multiple backends and suffixes (Base DNs). Here's a quick how to guide : http://ludopoitou.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/opends-tips-multiple-suffixes-with-opends/

Regards,

Ludovic